# Manipulate global variable as parameter in function

Tags: javascript, arrays, global-variables

I'm currently learning JavaScript and have a question about following code.

```js
var testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  arr.push(item);
  arr.shift();
}

console.log("Before: " + testArr);
nextInLine(testArr, 6);
console.log(" After: " + testArr);
```

The output is:

Before: `1,2,3,4,5`

After: `2,3,4,5,6`

I'm expecting no change in `testArr` and `Before` and `After` to be the exact same, because function-parameters are not global, as far as I know.

But the function actually manipulates the global variable `testArr` even though it's never mentioned in the function and just put in as a parameter.

I'd be very thankful if somebody could explain to me, why `testArr` is being manipulated in the function and how I could change that.

Comment: You're passing in the array as an argument to the function, what the arguments are named and wether or not they are global is irrelevant, the object passed in is still `testArr`

Comment: So there' s no difference in passing 'testArr' in as an argument and directly adressing it inside the function?

Comment: The difference is between manipulating the array object (which you do) and overwriting the variable with a new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as passing a variable by value or by reference in JS as there is in other programming languages such as C++.
The way you can deal with such things is to create a copy of the object you want to temporary modify. You can see the difference below

```js
function changeAgeImpure(person) {
    person.age = 25;
    return person;
}
var alex = {
    name: 'Alex',
    age: 30
};
var changedAlex = changeAgeImpure(alex);
console.log(alex); // -> { name: 'Alex', age: 25 }
console.log(changedAlex); // -> { name: 'Alex', age: 25 }
```

alex is a global variable but as you can see it is changed by the function changeAgeImpure.

The way you solve such things (in my example at least) is this way:

```js
function changeAgePure(person) {
    var newPersonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person));
    newPersonObj.age = 25;
    return newPersonObj;
}
var alex = {
    name: 'Alex',
    age: 30
};
var alexChanged = changeAgePure(alex);
console.log(alex); // -> { name: 'Alex', age: 30 }
console.log(alexChanged); // -> { name: 'Alex', age: 25 }
```

Now the alex variable will not be changed by the function as we have created an intermediate.

Comment: Guess I was used to C# too much, but I get it now. Thanks!